# mysql how to detect if column has no integer

Tags: mysql

Hi I have been trying to select the records whose column has no integer I have this piece of code and tried it different ways but still get back rows with P992142
P992142
P301716
P301716
P307162
P306522

which I don't want

```
 select practitioner_id
 from claimsprofinload
 WHERE practitioner_id not like '%[0-9]%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a regular expression in conjunction with `LIKE`, which is not valid. What you want is the [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) or `RLIKE` comparison.

Since that expression is evaluated as a more literal string, and since none of your rows have `[0-9]` literally in them, it matches all rows.

Comment: I see, but how do I get it to where its not like? as opposed to like since with rlike and regexp which gives me records with numbers

Comment: The first step is to write a regular expression which shows *only* records with numbers, and then invert it with `NOT`. You should try something like `'\d+'` to find records with digits in them. `%` is used by `LIKE` to represent arbitrary stuff, and `RLIKE` uses regular expression notation, where `%` is the literal percent character.